# Mixing standard and exact-width types

Tags: c, coding-style, type-conversion

Is it considered as bad style to have a mixture of exact width types (introduced by C99) and standard C types in one prototype definition? E.g.

```
  int some_func (uint32_t flags,
                   int on_off_switch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One generally uses an exact width type if the exact width is important to your code, for example if you absolutely need to know how many bits the representation of the integer will take up. It is certainly possible for some of the parameters to a function to have such constraints and others not to -- it all depends on precisely what you are doing.